# Finding the poles

Tags: complex-analysis

When you are trying to find a the poles and their respective orders of a function, are you allowed to simplify the original expression down.
For example, if someone has a function $$f=\frac{\cot z}{\sin z}$$
Are you allowed to write it as $$f=\frac{\cos z}{\sin^2 z}$$
and then find the poles?
I ask this because in lots of examples I have seen the expression is not simplified and I was wondering if simplification affected the final answer?

Comment: *Finding the poles* - [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poland) they are ! $($Unless those were not the Poles that you were looking for...$)$

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying has nothing to do with changing the answer, you are not changing any of the content within the formulation. As long as the equality within the given situation holds true the final answer shall be the same as well. Simplifying and rewriting is all about just writing it in differents way that may open up possibilities to attack the problem a different way, an example is
$$\int \ln x dx=\int 1\cdot \ln x dx$$
the first one is nigh impossible to do right of the bat, but the second one can use other form of machinery, integration by parts I believe it is called in english.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, as long as that form is easier to use to get your result. Sometimes, depending on what you have to do in the question, you need to change your equation to something different, so that it's easier to work with it.